# Passing tags as String for AWS CFT

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

tag in AWS CFT is parameter which takes JsonArray
`"Tags" : [ Tag, ... ],` Tag supports this
`{ "Key" : String, "Value" : String }` 
S3 bucket Tags can be referred for reference : [S3 Bucket tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-s3-bucket.html#cfn-s3-bucket-tags)

Now the issue is I want to pass multiple tags in json and instead of modifying the template for this.
example: [{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"},{"key3":"value3"}]

There should be a way to make tag as parameter ans pass the String in parameter.

I tried this approach to pass the tags

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "The template for S3 bucket",
    "Parameters": {
      "s3BucketName": {
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "test-bucket"
      },
      "projectName": {
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "test"
      },
      "tag": {
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "\"{\"Key\":\"project\",\"Value\":\"test\"}\",\"{\"Key\":\"owner\",\"Value\":\"test\"}\""
      }
    },
    "Resources": {
      "bucket": {
        "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
        "Properties": {
          "BucketName": {"Ref": "s3BucketName"},
          "PublicAccessBlockConfiguration": {
            "BlockPublicAcls": false,
            "BlockPublicPolicy": false,
            "IgnorePublicAcls": false,
            "RestrictPublicBuckets": false
          },
          "Tags": [{
            "Fn::Split": [",", {"Ref": "tag"}]
          }]
        }
      }
    },
    "Outputs": {
      "arn": {
        "Description": "The Arn of the S3 bucket.",
        "Value": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["bucket", "Arn"]}
      }
    }
  }
```

Error I got was
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSKln.png)

Thank you in advance!!